Деепричастные обороты, тесно связанные со сказуемым
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли обособлять деепричастные обороты в этих предложениях?

Он побрел по оживленной улице(,) не скрывая улыбки.
Она шла(,) прижимая к груди плюшевого мишку, купленного три года назад.

Читала правила, но все равно есть сомнения.
В первом случае, наверное, можно  перефразировать в "он побрел с улыбкой", но другие выражения вроде "не скрывая злости" в основном обособляются, судя по примерам.
Второе предложение похоже на пример "Он шел (как?) наклоня голову".
Но описывает ли прижимание к себе медвежонка... стиль походки? Одно дело, "шел хромая" или "опустив голову", а это...
Я как обычно: сама все усложнила и теперь ломаю голову. Буду признательна, если поможете разобраться.

1. В этом предложении я бы обособила деепричастный оборот.
Почему? Он находится в конце предложения и оторван от сказуемого. Между ними находится характеристика того места, по которому побрел человек (где? — по оживленной улице). Именно это представляется важным.
Он побрел по оживленной улице, не скрывая улыбки.
При другой конструкции предложения, мне кажется, возможно и не ставить запятую:
По оживленной улице он побрел не скрывая улыбки.
• Примеры
Прокурор смотрел на нее, не скрывая улыбки, — на таких он клевал (Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей).
Я отрицательно покачала головой, не скрывая улыбки (Яна Ясная. Игры с огнем).
Ванька старший спросил, не скрывая улыбки... (А. С. Макаренко. Книга для родителей).
2. И в этом предложении я бы тоже поставила запятую. Ну нет здесь, считаю, ни характеристики походки, ни указания на способ ходьбы.
Она шла, прижимая к груди плюшевого мишку, купленного три года назад.
• Примеры
Он отстал от товарищей и шел, прижимая к себе девицу за талию (В. В. Вересаев. Сестры).
Мелика шла, прижимая к груди цветок... (А. Зорич. Серый Тюльпан).
Девочка шла, прижимая к груди маленького дракончика (О. Сударикова. Академия света).
Едва передвигая ногами, с лицом, похожим на месиво, грязный, тот шел, прижимая к груди злосчастный футляр (А. Байкалов. Наш хлеб — разведка).
P. S. Он шел (как?) наклоня голову.
Лучше использовать нейтральное деепричастие "наклонив". "Наклоня" — это разговорная (или даже просторечная) форма, или поэтическая.
§ 20. Обособленные обстоятельства
"Что ты, милая, смотришь искоса, низко голову наклоня?.."

Второй ответ
ВЫВОД по теме NEW

У Розенталя информация о необособленных деепричастных оборотах дается в примечании как исключения (пункт 1, а всего там рассмотрены 5 пунктов), при этом определяется потенциальная ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ такого решения. Это в частности касается таких характеристик действия субъекта, как поза, мимика, жесты, стиль походки и т. д.. В примерах у Розенталя мы видим: откинув голову, наклонив голову, прихрамывая, стоя на носках и др.

Примечание.  Можно стоять прижав руки ко лбу, но это действие субъекта в пределах себя, однако при наличии внешнего объекта деепричастие будет обособлено как сопутствующее действие, а не как характеристика основного действия. Сравнить: шла, прижимая мишку.

После определения потенциальной возможности обстоятельственного значения оборота,  решается вопрос о его обособлении в РАЗНЫХ грамматических конструкциях. При этом возможны два варианта, как в примере с оборотом не скрывая улыбки.  Соответственно выбор делается по конкретному предложению с учетом контекста.

В заданном предложении  нужно выявить тесную СМЫСЛОВУЮ СВЯЗЬ оборота со сказуемым, что определяется по переходу логического ударения со сказуемого на оборот (только одно ударение ставится в таком словосочетании).  Тогда делается вывод, что оборот не обособляется. Обычно это однозначно видно в сложном предложении, а в простом зависит от контекста.
Такое решение задачи в ДВА ЭТАПА очень важно, так как можно сразу определить возможность или невозможность обстоятельственного значения, не переходя к анализу конструкции.  И напротив, смешение причин при анализе нежелательно.
И очень важно ВИДЕТЬ как один и тот же оборот в разных предложениях может быть как обособленным, так и необособленным.
Примечание. Приведенные примеры из литературы дают возможность увидеть, как автор решает свою задачу, но не стоит просто копировать это решение без анализа.

Sharon, "...что определяется по переходу логического ударения с оборота на сказуемое (только одно ударение в словосочетании)". Наверно, надо поменять местами: "...со сказуемого на оборот".

Да, спасибо, я исправила.

АЛЬТЕРНАТИВНОЕ РЕШЕНИЕ И ОБЪЯСНЕНИЕ
Пример 1.  Однозначное обособление:
Она шла, прижимая к груди плюшевого мишку, купленного три года назад.
Почему однозначное?
(1) Нельзя составить сочетание шла прижимая. Тем более нельзя составить сочетание  шла прижимая мишку (при наличии внешнего объекта). И совсем уж нельзя не обособить распространенный оборот (прижимая к груди плюшевого мишку, купленного три года назад) считая его обстоятельством.
Другими словами, у этого оборота нет потенциальной возможности быть необособленным.
Ближайший вариант без обособления (пример): Он стоял прижавшись к стЕне,  чтобы его не замЕтили. Здесь именно поза, в которой он стоял; кроме того, это сложное предложение.
Пример 2. Возможны оба варианта, выбор ПО КОНТЕКСТУ.
(1) Что ж, все не так плохо. Он побрел по оживленной Улице, не скрывая улЫбки.  Два ударения, предложение заканчивает тему.
(2) Он побрел по оживленной улице не скрывая улЫбки. Кажется, всё складывается в его пользу.  Одно ударение, предложение начинает тему (поэтому требуется ее продолжение в следующем предложении).
Пример со сложным предложением:
Он побрел по оживленной улице не скрывая улЫбки, так что прохожие посматривали на него с любопытством. Здесь однозначное необособление оборота в ударной позиции, одно ударение только на обороте.
МАТЕРИАЛЫ К ОТВЕТУ
Нужно правило? Это Розенталь, там есть вся необходимая информация.
Основное правило: обычно не обособляются одиночные деепричастия или малораспространенные  деепричастные обороты в роли обстоятельства образа действия, то есть их можно заменить синонимичным наречием или наречным сочетанием.
Этот вариант является исключительным и требует анализа структурной грамматики предложения, в котором использован оборот.
Интонационный анализ (проверка на слух).
При обособлении ударение падает на сказуемое и на оборот (два ударения), а без обособление ударение переходит на оборот (одно ударение).

• Также (в сложном предложении): Он побрел по оживленной улице не скрывая улЫбки, так что прохожие посматривали на него с любопытством. Здесь однозначное обособление, одно ударение. / (Одно ударение — запятая.) А запятой почему-то нет. • ...без обособление ударение переходит на оборот (одно ударение). / (Одно ударение — нет запятой.) /  Простите, ничего не понимаю...

Текст исправлен. Знали бы вы, сколько раз я его вчера правила! Но тема того стоила, чуть позже напишу второй ответ  с выводом.
